# Facebook posting on the wall/page with login using Facebook Connect

Tags: php, facebook

I want a PHP script that

1. logs into facebook with userid and password.
2. posts on the wall of a page.
3. Logs out.

Is it possible?

I am using php-sdk to post on the wall right now. But for that I have to log into my facebook account from the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It violates facebook developers TOS.

The only possible way to authenticate user - is to use regular API and regular authentication form.

**UPD**:

You could ask [offline_access](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) permission from the user. After that you'll have permanent tokens and will be able to post any time you want.

Comment: you see, the requirement is so, that what the users post on my site, i want to post it on my wall. felt like an easy requirement.

Comment: if its "your wall" then develop the app and allow it to use your wall to post updates. or explain to the "requestor" that its illegal.

Comment: Do as zerkms suggests and use the proper APIs. You authenticate with Facebook via Facebook Connect then use their API to create the wall posts. You do not log in to facebook.com with a username and password from your server.

Comment: @Nandini: see the update. You need to get token once per user. After if user gave you `offline_access` - you can use permanent tokens.

Comment: @Dan, I want to use proper APIs. And as it is I want to write on my wall only, it isn't spamming.